# Not able to pass entire html data at C# due to & symbol in the data

Tags: javascript, c#, json, ajax

I have a ajax post method where i pass json data using stringify and pass it to c# server side using ajax call.

The data consists of several rows of html table. The 2nd row has '&' in the input. So any data after & is not passed to the server side. only the data before '&' is passed

for e.g.

```
[{"FName":"Shesh","LName":"Chari","Department":"Automation"},
 {"FName":"Uma","LName":"uri","Department":"Invest & Ops"},
 {"FName":"Book","LName":"Mac","Department":"Ops"},
 {"FName":"Hard","LName":"Core","Department":"Invest"}]
```

As you can see above, instead of passing entire data as it is, it is passing this truncated data shown below. i guess it has to be due to & in the data. Any advice pls ?

```
[{"FName":"Shesh","LName":"Chari","Department":"Automation"},
 {"FName":"Uma","LName":"uri","Department":"Invest
```

Here is the JSON sent by ajax

```
var submitData = "=" + JSON.stringify($scope.gridOptions.rowData);

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'URL',
        data: submitData
    });
```

Comment: what does the posted data looks like in developer tools or fiddler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sanitise your Json data first:

```
var sanitiseString = $scope.gridOptions.rowData.replace("&", "&amp;")
var submitData = "=" + JSON.stringify(sanitiseString);

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'URL',
    data: submitData
});
```

Answer (score 1):

& is used in html as an escape sequence to display characters that are reserved in html (i.e. `<` becomes `&lt;` and `>` becomes `&gt;`). Because of this, & is reserved itself. You will need to sterilize your JSON string by converting all `&` to `&amp;`

See [Html entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp)

Comment: Thank you. just read about html entities and this is wat i needed.

Answer (score 0):

I would encode the ampersands before you send them to the server. You can do this by calling a simple regex on the columns that could contain an ampersand or by calling it on the entire string that you stringified.

```
var searchStr = "&";
var replaceStr = "%26";
var re = new RegExp(searchStr, "g");
```

Here is a really good post explaining what is happening and has a solution posted.

[Stringify with Ampersand](https://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/906941-how-escape-json-stringfy-ajax-call)